# Triple data for Pontrjagin dual of the Spin bordism group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cobordism

- It is said that the Pontrjagin dual of the 3-dimensional Spin bordism group of $BG$ for $G$ a finite group,
  $$
  \text{Hom}(Ω^{spin}_3(BG),\mathbb{R/Z}),
  $$
  can be expressed by triples of cochains $$(w, p, a),$$ 
  where 3-cochain $$w \in C^3(BG; \mathbb{R/Z}),$$
  2-cocycle 
  $$p \in Z^2(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)$$ and $a$ is a 1-cocycle 
  $$a \in Z^1(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2),$$ 
  satisfying the equation

  > $$dw + (1/2) p + (1/4) P(a^2) = 0.$$

Here $P$ is the Pontrjagin square.
Furthermore, by redefinition, we can use a different triple, $$(w', p, a)=(w-A^3/8,p,a),$$
satisfying the equation

> $$dw' + (1/2) p^2 = 0,$$

where 1-cochain $A \in C^1(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is the integral lift of $a$.

- It is said that the Pontrjagin dual of the 4-dimensional Spin bordism group of $BG$ for $G$ a finite group,
  $$
  \text{Hom}(Ω^{spin}_4(BG),\mathbb{R/Z}),
  $$
  can be expressed by triples of cochains $$(u, q, b),$$ 
  where 4-cochain $$u \in C^4(BG; \mathbb{R/Z}),$$
  3-cochain 
  $$q \in C^3(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)$$ and $b$ is a 2-cocycle 
  $$b \in Z^2(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2),$$ 
  satisfying the equation

  > $$du + b^2 = 0,$$

**perhaps with more constraints (to be confirmed?).**

> **Question:**
>
> 1. Is there some more concise and simple constraint for the triple of
>      $$
>    \text{Hom}(Ω^{spin}_4(BG),\mathbb{R/Z})?
>    $$
> 2. Is there an easy way to related the triple data of 
>      $
>    \text{Hom}(Ω^{spin}_3(BG),\mathbb{R/Z})
>    $
>      to the triple data of 
>      $
>    \text{Hom}(Ω^{spin}_4(BG),\mathbb{R/Z})
>    $? For example, by a **dimensional reduction from 4d to 3d**?

Refs: See for example,

[John Morgan's Spin Manifolds and Spin Bordism](http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/video_portal/video.php?id=2933)

[and arXiv 1612.02860 and 1803.08147](http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/video_portal/video.php?id=2933).